# images are clipped in portrait mode of iPhone X in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

The images placed in NORTH position of form or container are clipped in portrait mode of iPhone X. I think its due to layout of device as its perfectly rectangular.
So, how do I resolve this issue?

The issue is shown in figure

[image]

Its just one example. Even on other layout or form design I have the same issue.

Please advice on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need more padding in the title area. We already have a default `StatusBar` padding at the top of the device which pushes the icons downward but you should generally provide more vertical padding for `Title` or `TitleCommand` in your theme.